# When loading XML file using XMLLoader,i am getting error

Tags: xml, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am loading as below:

```
  A = LOAD'/home/sawanvijay/Datasets/xml/DATA_EMP.xml' USING       org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('ROW') AS (M:CHARARRAY);
```

The error is as shown below:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader using imports: [, 
org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /home/sawanvijay/pig_1453003016754.log
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you are not REGISTERING pigybank jar file. See instructions here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank
to register piggybank jar file.

Comment: Yes, looks like piggybank.jar is not in the classpath.